# Setting Viewbag from Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to set a value from my BaseController in my Razor views through the ViewBag, and after looking at StackOverflow I have implemented the following in my BaseController class:

```
           if (filterContext.Controller is BaseController)
                {
                    var controller = filterContext.Controller as BaseController;
                    controller.ViewBag.AccountType= AccountType;
                }
```

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and just wanted to check this code. Does it need to be in a conditional, or can I just set the controller as BaseController? What actually is the `filterContext.Controller is BaseController` checking?

Thanks

Comment: Not very clear where did you get that code so unclear what it tries to do... But TFM https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2 hopefully should help (also since it is rude ti suggest to actually R it I'm not sure how it will benefit you :))

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get some data in your views, using BaseController, I can help by my own experience with following code ( I translate it for VB, hope it's correct)
you can start by simply make your basecontroller.cs have the following line:

```
 using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Controllers
{
    public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        public BaseController()
        {
            ViewBag.MyData = "SomeData";
        }
    }
}
```

where MyData is the data that you want to use in views

and also in your home controller (if named HomeController ) you need to have this line :

```
public class HomeController : Controllers.BaseController
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use Filter Action for a simple ViewBag. ASP.NET MVC provides Action Filters for executing filtering logic either before or after an action method is called. Action Filters are custom attributes that provide declarative means to add pre-action and post-action behavior to the controller's action methods.

- OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext): Just before
  the action method is called.
- OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext): After the
  action method is called and before the result is executed (before
  view render).
- OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext): Just before
  the result is executed (before view render).
- OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext): After the
  result is executed (after the view is rendered).

For your problem, I suggest you to use a ViewModel Class that contains some field you need to access to them in multiple situations. Then, you can use Sessions with Singleton pattern to use this ViewModel Class. If you want to check user's "AccountType" in multiple views, Don't use ViewBag! There is session you can handle.